# Why the method used from Reactive ToObservable is not returning?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I was looking for solution for an issue I'm seeing with RX.

I have a list of objects: `List<Employee>`, with each employee having an ID and code number. There is a class in another dll, that takes each employee's id and code number and performs long-running processing which involves multiple db inserts. This db insert is in a static class in another dll.

My problem is the RX query I am using is only working works sometimes and NOT working most of the times. This means there is no wrong in the code. If run the code 10 times, 2 times it works properly and 8 times it fails. I'm using v4.0 of the .NET framework.

```
 IObservable<string> RunProcess(Employee emp)
    {           
        using (AnotherDLLClass p = new AnotherDLLClass(emp.id))
        {
            return Observable.Start(() => p.StartLongRun(emp.Code),   Scheduler.ThreadPool);
        }                        
    }
```

This employeedatas list may contains 1000 or 2000 records.

```
   EmployeeDatas.ToObservable().Select(x => RunProcess(x).Select(y => new { edata = x, retval = y }))
                    .Merge(10)
                    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
                    .Subscribe(x =>
                    {
                        SendReportStatus(x.retval.Item1, x.retval);                           
                    });
```

The StartLongRun() method in another dll has the following structure.

```
 public string StartLongRun(string code)
  {
     Method1(); // this method has a loop and each loop inserts data to db.
                // each loop calls DBHelper.Save() method to insert data to db.
                // sql con.opens and closes for each insert.

     Method2(); // doing exactly the same like Method1;

     return statusreport; // This return is not happening ????

  }
```

After running the app, when i check the DB, the values are inserting to the db
properly. Each second when i check the count of tables, datas are saved properly
and the count is increasing each seconds.

But why the method is not returning properly. The AnotherDLLClass has IDisposable implemented. When i put the break point on return part code, it is not hitting there.

It will hit there when EmployeeDatas has only 1 item. The first day when i implemeneted the code, it was working fine with 1000 items. The whole day I worked the same code and it was working fine with 1000 items.

But the next day when i run the app, the data are inserting properly but it is not returning the call. I dont understand this strange behaviour.

Pls throw some light on this and guide me.

Nobody has answered any solution to this strange behaviour. Is there any mistake i did here ? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (AnotherDLLClass p = new AnotherDLLClass(emp.id))
{
    return Observable.Start(() => p.StartLongRun(emp.Code),   Scheduler.ThreadPool);
}
```

In the code above, you are instantiating `p` in the `using` clause. Then you are using `p` in lambda expression that will be invoked asynchronously. It looks like the race condition. If the `() => p.StartLongRun` will be executed fast, then there is no exception. But after `}` of `using`, the `p` is disposed and internal lambda expression will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if i use without using clause, it is same. It will not return the call. Why I used using is that, inside the AnotherDLLClass is having lot of objects like another webservice proxy objects, ADO objects, etc. So for each call, it should dispose all the resources used by the anotherDLLClass. That is why I am used  using clause. There is no change in the result even if i create the instance of anotherDLLClass and call p.StartLongRun() method. DO you have any further idea about it ?

Comment: Another trouble I see in `Scheduler.ThreadPool`. According to the MSDN _This scheduler is ideal for short running operations._ Replace it by `Scheduler.NewThread`. According to the MSDN _This scheduler is ideal for long running operations._

Comment: Hi, I also tried with NewThread very long back. It is slower than ThreadPool. But it will not return. My LongRunning method will take maximum 15 - 20 seconds if i run with 1 employee object. That's why I used ThreadPool and it was very fast when i run for the first time. But I dont know what had happened. If i put the break point of the last return statement of the StartLongRun() method, it will never hit there.